# javascript parameter not working with a GSAP function

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I am using [Greensock](http://greensock.com/) and I have a really simple javascript function to execute the animation but when I try to invoke the function the parameter does not trigger.

Here is my function

```
var show = function(t){
    TweenMax.to('#el', 0.5, {scaleX:0, scaleY:0, delay:t, opacity:0, ease:Sine.easeIn});
}

show(0.5);//0.5 delay doesn't work
```

I've tested the function by hard-coding the delay value and it works.

Comment: Pretty sure you are *calling* `TweenMax.to(...)`. When called, `t` is not define, therefore it is probably undefined.

Comment: It didn't worked aye, thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Be sure to check through the docs for this, you may find some assistance there: http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/to/

Comment: Seems to work great. Here's proof: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdKoRN?editors=0010. Do you have a demo we can look at? There is probably something else going on in your code. Also, feel free to post in the GreenSock forums at http://greensock.com/forums/